# Installed gcc 12.1.0 in /usr/local/bin and now ubuntu cannot find and point to it

Tags: gcc, path, ubuntu-20.04

I have tried all the solutions of similar questions and none works.

I have installed gcc in **/usr/local/bin** and this my **PATH variable**

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/gcc-12.1.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

But when i run **gcc --version** command, my linux can't find it, why?

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

It **still points to the older 9.4.0 version**.
Could someone help me use the new version of the gcc compiler.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use update-alternatives tool to install gcc-12 as an alternative and to make it the default one.